# Bootstrap-vue bvModal msgBox - prevent closing on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm using bootstrap-vue's modals to open/close items on my application.

There's a few things that could go wrong, e.g. someone else has already performed a conflicting action on that item in the background. Therefore, I'd like to prevent the modal from closing, replace the button with a loading spinning and display some validation messages if the axios call fails.

I have the spinner, validation messages etc. working elsewhere, so I don't need help with that, however I'm struggling to find a way to access the bvModalEvt when using msgBox, to call .preventDefault() on, as per the documentation (https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#prevent-closing).

I've tried it on the this keyword within the promise (e.g. this.preventDefault(), and a few other things, such as on this.$bvModal.bvModalEvt (I didn't expect this to work, but I was getting desperate!)). All cause the msgBox catch block to fire, and the modal closes anyway, when called at the placeholder in my code below.

Here's the bare bones of my method:

```
openClose: function() {

    var self = this;

    this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm('Are you sure you want to ' + this.closeVerb + ' this item?', {
            title: 'Confirmation',
            size: 'md',
            cancelVariant: 'gray',
            okTitle: 'Confirm',
            cancelTitle: 'Dismiss',
            hideHeaderClose: false,
            centered: true
        })
        .then(function(value){                       

            // Prevent closing here

            if (value === true) {

                axios.post(postUrl, {
                        'action': self.closeVerb,
                    })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        // Handle here.
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // Catch validation errors here.
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
        })
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same issue as given below.

We can use the bootstrap-vue properties in the doc by converting it to lower camel case. Then you can prevent the modal from closing.

```
this.$bvModal.msgBoxConfirm("Message",
        {
           noCloseOnBackdrop: true,
           noCloseOnEsc: true
         })
```

You can view the properties in the doc using this link https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal/#modals

Answer (score 0):

In the same documentation you have linked, it says you can listen to events like this:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('bv::modal::show', (bvEvent, modalId) => {
      console.log('Modal is about to be shown', bvEvent, modalId)
    })
  }
}
```

And also, there are several events available to which you can listen.

Comment: Hi Teddy, thanks for your answer. If I called .preventDefault() on the the event using this method, would I not block the closing off all modals unless I implemented some workaround (e.g. checking a data item is true, which is only set to true just before the axios call)? I’ll give it a try in the meantime, but I assumed they’d be a cleaner way as they would be if I was not using the msgBox helper.

Comment: Yeah. It might not be perfect fit. Also, there is some modal id- maybe that can help to decide on canceling it.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have said all modals of this ID. I’ll let you know how I get on, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately whilst listening to bv::modal::hide, and calling .preventDefault() on the event does prevent closing, it also prevents execution of the then() on msgBox. I could try on "ok", but I don't seem to be able to hit that event - I've tried this.$root.$on('ok', ...), this.$on(...) and this.bvModal.$on(...) - the latest throws an error in the console. Any ideas as to how I should be listening to "ok"?

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to separate the validation logic from the msgBox logic.

when the confirm msgBox returns a result, open your "spinner" and do your axios post, and if it fails, open a new msgBox explaining the situation.

Message Box content is not reactive (so you can't dynamically update it's content)